# How can I clone a Windows drive to an SSD with Mac already on it?

Tags: windows, mac, ssd, clone

I have a 250gb SSD partitioned half for macOS Sierra and the other half NTFS. I'm trying to clone my HDD with Windows 10 on it to my NTFS partition on the SSD, but I haven't had any luck in trying to clone it with both Mac and Windows. Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

"Acronis" will do this in **sector** copy mode. Slow but it does it. There may be other copy software that does this. Any one else know?